# How to boost flutter performance?

Tags: dart, flutter

How to boost flutter performance and speed up our application.
As I am working on a larg application and I worried about performance issue, becuase I need a supper fast app.

Here I have a large list of items like a chat application and there is something mentioned below that I am worry about:
1: I need scrolling more than 3000 items smoothly
2: I need to update specific item during chat, like: seen, delived, sent or deleted.
3: and navigation

In react-native there is a lot of way like using `PureComponent`
or `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)` function to decrease rendering.

for example in react-native we can split a big list Component into sub Component  of items, then we can use `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)` and prevent any rendering does not depends to the current Item.

This aprroach help us to just render the item we need to update.
and also there is alot of other way we can use for speed up our application.

although One big problem I encounted in react-native is, if we scroll very fast more than 300 items there a blank space appears instaed of list items.

So my question is how to find same tips in `FLUTTER`, I mean Is there a tips/trick for `flutter` like I mentioned above in `react-native`? if yes please help me with a simple examples.
Thank you in befor

Answer (score 1):

> Here I have a large list of items like a chat application and there is something mentioned below that I am worry about: 1: I need scrolling more than 3000 items smoothly 2: I need to update specific item during chat, like: seen, delived, sent or deleted. 3: and navigation

Use `ListView.builder()` widget to create smooth scrollable list without any length without any performance issue.

It's functionality basically corresponds to RecyclerView (Native Android).
The items which are not visible on the screen are not rendered so it doesn't practically matter how many items exist in the list in total.

Flutter handles all those minor things for you so that you can focus on other important aspects of your app. Flutter and RN are similar to some extent but they are not the same.

Working Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

List<String> litems = ["1","2","Third","4"];

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctxt) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new ListDisplay(),
    );
  }
}
class ListDisplay extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build (BuildContext ctxt) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Dynamic Demo"),),
      body:  new ListView.builder(
                   itemCount: litems.length,
                   itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
                     return new Text(litems[index]);
    }
  )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you still face the same issue, then try running the app in `release mode`. That should surely solve your issue for the above example.

If you want some more tips on increasing your app's overall performance head over to the links given  below,

https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/best-practices

https://medium.com/flutter-community/improve-your-flutter-app-performance-split-your-widgets-935f97e93f7d

To run your app in release mode execute `flutter run --release` in your app's terminal to run your app in release mode.

Comment: ListView.Builder is good for list with very large items as it only build widgets that are visible on the screen but according to my experience when the widget goes out of the screen then that widget is destroyed and again re-created when the widget needs to appear back to the screen. And if the widget build method is slow (maybe due to heavy computation) then the scrolling will definitely lag.

Comment: It depends on the type of widget..Stateful widgets aren't really destroyed in that sense

Answer (score 0):

While using the **provider** for example if have data that you will need only on a specific page and this data will be temporarily viewed avoid adding it to the provider I highly advise you to use **multiple providers**. so you avoid rebuiding all the screen components when changing the state. also if you have too many **stateless** widgets in a screen and you have only few widgets that are **stateful**. you should wrap those with state changeable components (stateful) with consumer so when notifying the UI of a state change only those concerne will be updated. that will help **avoiding rebuid** entire screen.

Answer (score 0):

- Use **Stateless widgets** instead of **Stateful widgets** in the cases that you dont have to use it  so you dont have always to rebuild your application , and try to not Use **setState()** methode because it is heavy and expensive and use instead of it **StreamBuilder()**
- Split Larger **Widgets** into smaller widgets
- Use **Const** keyword ,  Using the const keyword wherever applicable can be a great way to reduce memory usage , and you can use the Const KeyWord in lot of places like EdgeInsets, Color and Text , and Also in Constructors

`const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 4, 16, 8); const Color lightGray = Color(0xFFFEFEFE); const Text('This is a static text')`

Also in the constructors:

```
Column(children: [
const JDSearchIcon(),
InkWell(....),
const JDSearchIcon(),],),
```

- Render only widgets that are visible on the screen , When you are dealing with a large vertical or horizontal list of widgets, you should avoid using a solution that creates all the widgets visible on the screen at once. Instead, try using ListView.builder to improve the performance of your flutter app.

  `ListView.builder(`

  `itemCount: dataSource.length,`

  `itemBuilder: (context, index) {`

  `return Tweet(dataSource[index]);`
  `},`
  `)`